# wordpress wpdb update difficulties

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

Suppose I have a table in my wp database fruits:

```
            CREATE TABLE `fruits` (
                `fruit` varchar(99),
                `istasty` tinyint(1)
            )

            INSERT INTO `fruits` (`fruit`, `istasty`) VALUES
            ('pear', 1),
            ('peach', 1),
            ('rotten strawberry', 1),
            ('strawberry', 1),
            ('banana', 1),
            ('apple', 1);
```

the goal is to update istasty to 0 in the 'rotten strawberry' row.

the [class reference for wpdb in the wordpress codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows) gives:

> $wpdb->update( $table, $data, $where, $format = null, $where_format = null );

so I've attempted the following:

```
            $wpdb->update( 
                'fruits', 
                array( 
                    'fruit' => 'rotten strawberry',
                    'istasty' => '0'
                ), 
                array( 'fruit' => 'rotten strawberry' ), 
                array( 
                    '%s',   // value1
                    '%d'    // value2
                ), 
                array( '%d' ) 
            );
```

Apparently this updates EVERY record to 'rotten strawberry', '1'.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing up that last array from `array( '%d'` ) into `array( '%s' )`. You are now telling the script that the where variable is an integer, which it is not.

Also you could remove `'fruit' => 'rotten strawberry'` from your first array. In this array you place whatever you want to update. And all you want to do is set *istasty* to *0*.